# Prevent IP session hijacking

Tags: network, spoofing, ip-spoofing

I was thinking of the following scenario :

- a network is behind a router (performing NAT) and firewall
- this firewall denies all unsollicited incoming packet
- a user on a computer of the network opens a browser, types in “http://www.company1.com”. He therefore opens a port to establish a communication with a socket on company’s side. Notice that the connection is http.

Our user feels secure but there is an attacker outside who is sending constantly a spoofed TCP/IP packet with the source IP address of one of company1’s server, and a random TCP number. He uses a malicious payload.

In my mind, there is a risk there that (rarely) the attacker hits is target, meaning that he hits a router where the firewall will let the packet inside the network because a connection was established indeed with the IP the attacker is spoofing. That way the attacker is able to make the computer on the network process the attacker’s data.

He makes up for the rarity of a "hit" by sending his malicious packet to many IPs.

The scenario is even more favorable for the attacker with UDP.

What security measure in common routers/firewall prevent that?

EDIT : the question was marked as a duplicate with 4 others. It is not, here’s why : in my question I am suggesting that only 1 tcp or udp packet from the attacker is seen, received and processed by the computer in the network. You can do some damage with only 1 packet if you are being crafty. The 4 other questions ask whether a connection can be established, or whether the response can be sent to the attacker.
Schroeder suggests that this is clearly impossible, but everything I read in these 4 links point to this being possible (since the answers often highlight the main issue being that the TCP response would not go to the attacker - which again I am not talking about here).
Please give me some technical arguments instead of pointing to different questions, or suggesting I read basic TCP/IP tutorial.

Comment: Note: there's no such thing as a "low TCP number" any more. They start from a random number.

Comment: I did indeed explain: sockets and sessions. TCP sequence numbers, and stateful firewalls. Again, this is not a *security issue*. This is pure TCP/IP. And that's all besides the ubiquitous use of TLS, which would make this even more impossible.

Comment: This is clearly a security question, as an attacker is involved. When you read most resources on pure tcp/ip, there is no or little mention to attacks. Knowledge of a protocol and knowledge about guarding against that protocol are two different things (though they overlap).

Comment: Duplicates one and two both provide technical reasons why this isn't a legitimate concern.

Comment: @Xander Can you please explain a bit more? They talk about TCP sequences numbers. But those are only 32 bits in length, so by the birthday attack you have a 50% chance of hitting a correct sequence number with 65536 attempts (is that too much to be practical?)

Comment: @Xander thanks. To me it reads a little differently. In the scenario I described, there is actually no TCP sequence prediction. It is just brute force sending always the same stuff, and landing on the right one by chance. The fix described in the other links is to make the sequence number hard to predict. But that's not the attack I have in mind here.

Comment: That's where the importance of the second duplicate comes in, and @schroeder's earlier comment.  It isn't just the sequence number you have to brute-force, but also the sockets that make up the session. And since you don't get feedback, you have to blindly brute-force them all simultaneously, which is infeasible.

Comment: Right, the attacker basically has to assume the following info (sequence_num, source_ip, source_port, remote_ip, remote_port). remote_ip and remote_port are not much of a guess (this is company1_ip and the port will be known, say 80). so really it's about blindly brute-forcing (sequence_num, source_ip, source_port). I understand that the attacker would need to send many many packets before having a hit. And then they have only 1 packet to cause damage. But I am questionning whether that's stricly, mathematically, "infeasible", or whether it is actually feasible, but just costly.

Comment: @nobody The birthday attack doesn't apply here. Any arbitrary collision won't do, you you need to identify a single specific value chosen by the authentic sender, so it will take on average two billion attempts (n/2) to find the valid sequence number with a 50% probability.

Comment: @DevShark It is mathematically infeasible.

Comment: @DevShark and that's just to get the *TCP/IP* packet accepted at all. But since there is already a connection to the legitimate target, then you have the session identifier at the application level. And all of this before security controls ever kick in (like TLS). As I've tried to explain, since you are asking about the situation *without* security (TLS), it's a pure protocol question.

Comment: @DevShark  It is mathematically infeasible since you are not only dealing with large numbers, but the right large number is only right for a fraction of a second... Please look up sequence numbers.

Comment: Right, it is mathematically possible, but the probability of success is prohibitively low. That was my initial impression when thinking about this and from reading the other questions, but it's good to confirm. Thank you for taking the time to explain.

Comment: @Xander Thanks for clarifying! Probability theory always confuses me.

Comment: @schroeder I think we are talking about slightly different concepts. I am saying it is mathematically possible, but very unlikely. For example if I say I have to choose exactly the right atom in the universe to solve a problem, and I have to find it at the right second, it is mathematically possible, but very unlikely. This is the same situation here. It is mathematically possible for an attacker to succeed, it is in the realm of possible events. However, it is very unlikely. I think you mean to say it is "practically impossible".

Comment: @DevShark I used the word "infeasible". That implies that it is possible, As an attack, it is infeasible. Your odds are astronomical. And then that's just to get the TCP/IP packet to not get rejected at the network level. Then you have all the other things in the OSI stack that get in the way making it impossible.

Comment: "Infeasible" alone is ok to describe that situation. The issue is with the phrase "mathematically infeasible". Combined with your first statement that TLS "would make this even more impossible", it gave the impression that you meant it is not mathematically  possible.

But no worries, I think things are clear now. Thanks for taking the time to explain your point.